# What are the disadvantages of an M:N threading model (e.g. goroutines)?

Tags: multithreading, go, language-agnostic, erlang, programming-languages

[M:N threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)#M:N_.28hybrid_threading.29) is a model which maps M user threads onto N kernel threads. This enables a large number (M) of user threads to be created, due to their light weight, which still allowing (N-way) parallelism.

This seems like a win-win to me, so why do so few languages/implementations use this threading model? The only examples I am aware of are Go's "goroutines" and Erlang's processes.

What are the disadvantages of M:N threading? Why do other languages not use this threading model that, on the surface, seems so promising?

Comment: Rust uses the actor model of Erlang and Rust is faster than Go. https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch16-00-concurrency.html

Comment: Other related languages include Occam and Limbo.

Comment: There are performance issues and there are abstraction & correctness issues. Different people will have different views on this. IMO, the use of coroutines / goroutines / occam processes etc is an easier abstraction to use when writing code that describes concurrent behaviour than the mainstream reactive / callback-driven alternative. Often, the performance of lightweight threads is less good than the mainstream (which might be bluntly described as hand-rolled approach using OS threads). But sometimes the reverse is true if parallel execution occurs efficiently. /Just my opinion/.

Comment: Because this question was closed on Stack Overflow, I have asked it again [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammingLanguages/comments/6mm4v1/what_are_the_disadvantages_of_an_mn_threading/?ref=share&ref_source=link).

Answer (score 0):

Partly it's because "it's what everyone else is doing". While M:N threading did exist before Go, all mainstream languages (C, C++, Perl, Java, C#, Python, Ruby, PHP) used threads, and many of them (Python, Ruby) did that poorly. Go is the first popular language that shows M:N threading can work well.

Partly it's because threads are the native primitive of the OS.

Implementing M:N threading makes interop with OS code/C libraries harder and a bit slower. When calling C/OS code, Go has to switch from small goroutine stack to regular OS stack.

Many other popular languages (Python, Ruby) rely more heavily on ability to call C code than Go so it's more important for them to optimize for that.

Good M:N threading interop with OS/C code is not impossible (Go does that decently) but it's easier to do if you do what OS does.